# Submit, mysql query + http request to a SMS gateway using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am receiving some data to my **confirm.php** file. The confirm.php file contains the below code.
I am stuck on the javascript and would really appreciate all input and help.

**What I want my javascript to do is:** 
 When the user click the submit "Approve & SMS" button, a query is sent to my DB (with customer, tasks and user data) and at the same time a http request is sent to a SMS gateway. After the user has clicked the "Approve & SMS" button, an alert box pops up and when the user click OK in the alert box, I want to redirect the user to my index.php.

**Note**: I do not need suggestion on the actually mysql query, just on how to make the magic trigger to send a query + the http request with javascript (**it do not have to be purely javascript suggestions,, all solutions are welcome as long as they solve my problem).**

**CONFIRM.PHP**

```
<?php
    //check session to get customer
    if(!isset($_SESSION['customer'])) {
        die('$'."_SESSION['customer'] Session ended");
    } else {
        $customer = $_SESSION['customer'];
        echo $customer;
    }
?>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL 
    $tasks = $_POST['tasks'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
 ?>
```

**SMS API stuff**

```
<?php
//Create $sms_url to send sms to customer
// The necessary variables
$sms_message = ("this is a text");
$sms_url = "http://the.domain/sms/";
$sms_url .= "?message=" . urlencode($sms_message); //messages
$sms_url .= "&recipient=$customer"; // Recipient
$sms_url .= "&from=" . urlencode("name company."); // Sendername
//echo $sms_url;
?>
```

**SOME HTML**

```
<form id="sms_insert_data" action="???" method="POST">
<input class="submit" name="showWordCard" type="submit" value="Approve & SMS"></input>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.submit').click(function(){
  var foo = alert('Card created and SMS sent to: <?php echo json_encode($customer); ?>');
  window.location = "..//index.php"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery ajax to send a http request to a php script and/or to your sms gateway.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/